# step type "slack/status" is not a valid type

Tags: slack, circleci, circleci-workflows

I am trying to integrate slack with circle ci only for specific jobs and following this documentation : https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/circleci/slack. I am getting this error **step type "slack/status" is not a valid type** every time that job is run. Any help/feedback is appreciated, This is what I have done so far:

```
   version: 2
   orbs:
     slack: circleci/slack@3.4.2
   
  jobs:

    slack_notification:
      docker:
        - image: circleci/node
      steps:
        - run: exit 0
        - slack/status:
            fail_only: false
            channel: {Channel ID}
            failure_message: ':red_circle: A $CIRCLE_JOB job has failed!'
            success_message: ':tada: A $CIRCLE_JOB job has succeeded!'
            include_project_field: true
            include_job_number_field: true
            url: 'https://circleci.com/workflow-run/${CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID}' 
            webhook: {webhook}

   workflows:
     version: 2
     jobs:
       - job_1:
         { Job steps}

       - slack_notification:
           requires:
             - {job_1}
           filters:
             branches:
              only:
                - {branch}
```

Answer (score 0):

use version: 2.1 instead
workflow version 2 is fine

Comment: This may be the right answer and that's good, but it could be even better if you are able to support your information with documentation or an explanation regarding why the newer version solves the problem.